# Variable is undefined outside of the function

Tags: node.js, express, variables

Can someone please help me out with this? I'm getting an error 'count is not defined' when executing the below code. I'm trying to create a countdown clock in node.js. If I log the timer variable inside the function it works but outside of the function, it is undefined.

```
const getOrder = async(request, response) => {
const data = await knex("orderbook_table").select()
const time_data = await knex("orderbook_table").select("timestamp")

console.log(time_data)

var timer;

setInterval(function count() {

    for (var i = 0; i < time_data.length; i++) {
        //console.log(tableRows[i]);
        var entryDate = time_data[i].timestamp;
        const second = 1000,
            minute = second * 60,
            hour = minute * 60,
            day = hour * 24;

        countDown = new Date(entryDate).getTime();

        let now = new Date().getTime();
        distance = countDown - now;

        days = Math.floor(distance / (day));
        hours = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
        minutes = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
        seconds = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

        timer = days + "d:" + hours + "h:" + minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";

        //console.log(timer);
    }
}, 1000);

var orderStr = data;

count();
console.log(timer);

response.send({ orderStr });
//refresh()
```

Comment: "*I'm getting an error 'count is not defined' when executing the below code.*" because you haven't declared `count`. You just have a named function expression, which doesn't create a binding outside of its body.

Comment: 1. Create the `count` function in the global scope. 2. Pass the `count` function to `setInterval`: `setInterval(count, 1000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count` function is defined and scoped under the setTimer, you should create the function as callback outside of `setInterval` then call within that setInterval the created function

You can give a look to this [previously answered thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488591/how-to-kick-ass-pass-scope-through-setinterval) or to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: Scope is not at all involved here. The `count` function isn't in *a different* scope but literally not registered as a name. Because it's a function expression, rather than a function declaration.